# Python unit testing: psycopg2 query coverage

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage, psycopg2

We're doing unit testing via the usual unittest module of python. This works very well with coverage, but it does not really help to find out if queries are tested well. Is there any tool to collect coverage information for queries used in psycopg2? Some of our queries are quite complex and as such can have multiple paths, depending on the data that is currently in the database.

I'd split up the queries, but that would have a bigger performance impact, as the query planner will not be able to optimize as well as in a single query.

[TL;DR]: Is there any tool to collect coverage information for queries used in psycopg2?